# msys2 and headers in the 'wrong' place

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, header, msys2

Ok, so, I'm trying to build a third party library with msys2 and I've run into a problem with a few headers, such as gtk.h; the library I'm trying to build expects this to be located via `#include <gtk/gtk.h>`.

Now, experience on Linux tells me that would be correct under a normal linux environment; however, in the case of gtk, it seems it would have to be gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h, which seems like an error in msys to me - is there some sort of selection step I've missed in setting up my msys2 environment? Like the 'eselect' system under Gentoo, something like 'pselect gtk-3.0' that would create a linked directory to gtk-3.0/gtk just called gtk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have installed the `mingw-w64-i686-gtk3` package with pacman and that you are running in a MinGW 32-bit shell (MSYS2 has three different flavors of shell that use different toolchains), you can run this command to get the required compile flags for GTK3:

```
pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags
```

Most build systems have some kind of support for calling `pkg-config`.  It is basically the standard way to get information about your dependencies.

When it's time to link your program, you should replace `--cflags` in the comand above with `--libs`.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to tell the compiler where to find the include directory:

```
-I/some/path/to/gtk-3.0
```

Comment: true, I could; however, it seems somewhat overdone when the file is, say, c:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk\gtk.h, to have state -Ic:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\ when c:\msys64\mingw64\include\ is already on the path.

Comment: Well, tough luck.  This is how it's done.  If you don't like it, you can change the source code to `#include <gtk-3.0/...>`.  Or make your own symlink from `gtk` to `gtk-3.0/gtk`.